# Chrome source maps not working with Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

I can't get the source maps working! Chrome says "Source Map detected" but no dice. I'm using Babel6, Node 6.5 and new `--inspect` with Chrome DevTools. I think I've spent hours trying so many different things and other people seem to have the same issues...PLEASE HELP :(

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145

```
babel source --out-dir dist --source-maps && node --inspect dist/server
```

I suspect it has something to do with the extra fluff that is added to the script (the script itself doesn't have code after the sourceMappingURL):

[image]

Comment: I not sure i understand why you need the source map. The code is not minified and you don't mention that you wrote the code with coffescript or typescript etc.

Comment: It is implied with Babel. I want to debug in the original ES6 code, not the transpiled mess of ES5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been fighting this all day, only to realize it seems to be a limitation currently in node: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8369#issuecomment-244089784